# Disk space on Windows share over SMB from Linux

Tags: python, linux, networking, smb, diskspace

I'm developing an addon for [XBMC](http://www.xbmc.org) that checks for files to delete based upon disk space availability. I am having trouble checking for disk space on my Windows 7 share from Linux-based operating systems, including Raspberry Pi, Ubuntu, etc. XBMC uses python 2.6 by the way.

My current code is as follows:

```
import os

loc1 = "smb://geert/e/Downloads/"
loc2 = "/home/"

stats = os.statvfs(loc)
print stats
```

In the code above `loc1` is the path that gives trouble. It appears as if the `statvfs` module cannot handle `smb://` paths, because I keep getting the error below. When I try `loc2` everything is fine. I have searched high and low for a definitive answer to this question, but could not find any.

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 statvfstest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "statvfstest.py", line 8, in <module>
    print os.statvfs(loc)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'smb://geert/e/Downloads/'
```

**Steps I have tried:**

- I have tried the `psutil` module as I have seen recommended frequently in other questions on this site, but it appears to merely be a wrapper for the `statvfs` method and thus results in the same error message, only with a longer stack trace.
- Mounted the `e` share and used the proper credentials. The share is visible from the file manager and shows the correct contents.
- I have added credentials to `loc1` in the form `smb://user:pass@geert/e/Downloads/`.
- Any combination of the above three methods, all to no avail.

Could you please help me reliably test the amount of free space available on my Windows share, from a Linux PC, using smb network paths? If at all possible I would like to refrain from adding extra modules to my addon just for this feature, to ensure it stays lightweight.

Thanks in advance,

Geert

Comment: When you mount the share do you stil use `"smb://share/"` as the location or for example `"/mnt/share/"`?

Comment: Yes (I think) I do (my experience with linux is limited). The location bar in the file manager displays `smb://geert/e/Downloads` and the sidebar shows `e on geert`.

Comment: Ok. I'm not _the_ expert either but I'll try to explain. When you _mount_ a disk / partition / share in linux it becomes part of the file system in a certain location: the mount point. E.g a USB drive could become available in the folder e.g. `/media/drive/`. In a way a mount point is the equivalent of a drive letter in Windows.

Comment: Because the share becomes part of the file system you don't have to address it as a network location and maybe `statvfs` can work with it too. So perhaps you could check if your code works when you use the mount point as location. 
The mount point can be any folder (AFAIK) but for Ubuntu for smb it should be [one of these by default.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33480/how-do-i-navigate-to-a-samba-location-ive-mounted-in-nautilus-on-the-command-li/33513#33513) Don't know if this is different on XBMC...

Comment: Okay that sounds very reasonable. XMBC uses an internal mounting process that isn't transparent to the user. I will ask around on the XBMC forums and report what I find.